flutter gesture Null check operator used on a null value
I want to ask about the problem as in the following picture.
this problem is related with dart null safety but i am unable to fix this issue.
Error is in onYesPressed!()
every time I click the confirm or yes button it always gets an error like that, please help.
Note: the issue is if i'm used postgres db, in mysql running so well
Thank You
and the code i have



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:kt_pos/util/color_resources.dart';
import 'package:kt_pos/util/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:kt_pos/util/images.dart';
import 'package:kt_pos/common/widgets/custom_button_widget.dart';
class ConfirmPurchaseDialogWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function? onYesPressed;
  const ConfirmPurchaseDialogWidget({Key? key, required this.onYesPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.paddingSizeSmall)),
        child: Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.paddingSizeExtraLarge),
        height: 210,
          child: Column(children: [
          SizedBox(width: 70,height: 70,
            child: Image.asset(Images.confirmPurchase),),
          Text('confirm_purchase'.tr),
          Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.paddingSizeDefault),
          child: SizedBox(height: 40,
            child: Row(children: [
              Expanded(child: CustomButtonWidget(buttonText: 'cancel'.tr,
                  buttonColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,textColor: ColorResources.getTextColor(),isClear: true,
                  onPressed: ()=> Get.back())),
              const SizedBox(width: Dimensions.paddingSizeDefault),
              Expanded(child: CustomButtonWidget(buttonText: 'yes'.tr, onPressed: (){
                onYesPressed!();
                Get.back();
              },)),
            ],),
          ),
        )

      ],),
    ));
  }
}






onYesPressed!()   here  onYesPressed is null .you might have passed null to this parameter where ConfirmPurchaseDialogWidget is created.
